# Modifying column with in a table (CSS)

Tags: java, html, css, tablelayout, spacing

```
middle += "<tr class='tRow'>"
               + "<td>"
                  + "<a href='" + output.get(i).get("itemURL") + "'>"
                  + gallery 
                  + "</a>"
               + "</td>"
               + "<td class='title'>"
                  + "<a href='" + output.get(i).get("itemURL") + "'>"
                  + ""+ (output.get(i).get("title")).replaceAll("\"","\'\'")+"" // replaces quatations into '

                  + "</a>"
               + "</td>"
               +
```

The column having name 'title' (class name) needs to be affected by style sheet to decrease the width of column. Only that single column needs to be affected. There are more columns.
This is CSS:

```
td.title{
          width:18%;
         }
```

But this CSS affects all the columns in the table. The width of rest columns affected , but some of them has the width different than specified by CSS. I tried inline style sheet, but still it affects all columns.
What is the problem? Cheers

Additional details:
 private String getBeginning(int tableNumber)
    {

```
      return "<html><head><title>"+ (tableNumber - 1)+"</title>"

          + "</head><body>"
          + "<table id='example' class='tablesorter' cellpadding='3' >" // border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2'
          + "<thead>"
                 + "<tr class='tHead'>"
                       + "<th/>"
                       + "<th>Title</th>"
                       + "<th>Total Price</th>"
                       + "<th>Currency</th>"
                       + "<th>Condition</th>"
                       + "<th>Location</th>"
                       + "<th>End Time</th>"
                       + "<th>Map</th>"
                + "</tr>"
          + "</thead>"
          + "<tbody>";
}


       middle += "<tr class='tRow'>"
               + "<td>"
                  + "<a href='" + output.get(i).get("itemURL") + "'>"
                  + gallery 
                  + "</a>"
               + "</td>"
               + "<td class='title'>"
                  + "<a href='" + output.get(i).get("itemURL") + "'>"
                  + ""+ (output.get(i).get("title")).replaceAll("\"","\'\'")+"" // replaces quatations into '

                  + "</a>"
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
                  + ""+output.get(i).get("total") +""
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
                  + ""+output.get(i).get("currency")+""
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
                  + ""+condition+""
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
                  + ""+output.get(i).get("location")+""
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
                  + ""+output.get(i).get("endTime").split("T")[0]+""
               + "</td>"
               + "<td>"
               + "<a href='" + getMap(location, postCode, "0") + "'>"
               + "<img src='" + getMap(location, postCode, "1") + "'> "
               +"</a>"
               + "</td>"
               + "</tr>";
```

String end ="";

I am running this Web app on Firefox 3.6.11. Did not try to run it on different browsers.

Comment: Can you please provide a complete sample of the rendered HTML?  Also, can you please state which browser(s) and version(s) this is failing for?

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note here is that percentage values relate to the amount of space available to the table, not to the page or containing div. Try using an absolute value like `200`. It might also complicate things if you already have `width` set on the table meaning you're not letting the browser decide how wide it will end up.

Without seeing the rest of your code and knowing what context the table is in, or whether you have width set on the table itself, I can tell you that setting a width on a single column when the table itself has a width set on it will change the width of the other columns as they bump about to fill up space. In this situation it is generally a good idea to let the size of the cells sort themselves out, as the algorithm used to set the width is very dynamic. Alternatively you could be very strict and set the width on each column exactly as you will want it to appear.

To read up on the subject, see [the HTML specification.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.4)

Comment: The width is on the table itself is not set. This is what set on the table:  #output{
               position:relative;
               right:-140px;
             }